# How do I detect variables in a python eval expression

Tags: python

Let's say i get a string to eval

```
temperature*x
```

And I have two sets of variables - the easy one:

```
easy_ns = {'x':3, 'y':4}
```

And a harder one:

```
harder = ['temperature', 'sumofall']
```

Each of which will take significant time to calculate and I don't want to calculate them unless they are part of the user supplied expression

E.g. I don't want to start the detection of "temperature" unless I know it is required

I may have some variables in my namespace that are "inexpensive" but others I would like to postpone calculating as much as possible

How do I get a list of variables from my eval string before it is evaluated

I know I can try: eval() except: and I will get a:

```
NameError: name 'temperature' is not defined
```

Is there a pythonic way of extracting the exact variable name?

Is there a nice way to build your namespace for lazy evaluation?

Something like

```
namespace = {'x':3, 'y':4, 'temperature':lazy_temperature_function}
```

So that only when my expression is evaluated

```
res=eval('temperature*x')
```

is my lazy temperature function called

And *yes* of course - I absolutely do have to use 'eval' - that is why I have posted these questions

The scenario is that I get an input file with set of keys and values and then the user can supply an expression he wants me to calculate from a combination of those values and some generated variables that I do not want to calculate unless the user includes them in his/her expression

Comment: Why are you doing this to yourself? This sounds like it is going to be hard to program and hard to use. What are you really wanting to do?

Comment: Have you considered absolutely not trying to evaluate the string?

Comment: you need to get proper expression evaluator and not abuse eval

Comment: You want to parse a code, but on execute it (at least yet). That's what [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) is for.

Comment: I refuse to believe that you "absolustely have to use eval." Either you or another programmer whose output you are consuming has made a terrible decision that has left you in this spot. You should undo that decision if at all possible.

Comment: How do you have  `temperature` if it is not a variable anywhere in the scope of where you are calling eval on the string? I have no idea what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, other options have been considered but where not feasible

Comment: *"Is there a nice way to build your namespace for lazy evaluation?"* - there is no reason your namespace couldn't be a dictionary wrapper with a lazy implementation of `__getitem__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "there is no reason your namespace couldn't be a dictionary wrapper with a lazy implementation of __getitem__" - that sounds like a perfect pythonic solution with good performance. You should write an answer with that - thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my answer with something like that. Implementation is not with a dict wrapper though - which would probably be nicer. Just wanted to give an example of building a namespace dynamically.

Comment: @HolgerBille why don't you have a go at writing it? If you get stuck, give a [mcve] and a clear problem statement. Why should I have all the fun?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I will write it and also now I will modify the headline from "How do I detect variables in a python eval expression" to "How do I lazy evaluate variables in a python eval expression"

Comment: Changing the title but not actually editing the body accordingly doesn't seem too helpful. Why don't you ask the answerers if they mind deleting their posts so that you can delete the question, and ask another later if you still need to?

Comment: You are right - I will do it the other way around though. Post the other question and then see if I can close this one. @AndréLaszlo is this ok? Thank you for your answer, which I have upvoted. Please post it again when I post the next

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could, if you really really have to, parse the code using the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module. The `ast.parse` helper will give you an AST tree representation of the code:

```
import ast
code = "temperature*x"
st = ast.parse(code)
for node in ast.walk(st):
    if type(node) is ast.Name:
        print(node.id)
```

This will print:

```
temperature
x
```

So this only extracts the variable names, like you said. It seems like a first step, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do so maybe a different approach is better.

**Edit**: If I understand your problem correctly, you want some values to be calculated only if they appear in an expression? I tried something like this:

```
>>> import ast
>>> code = "temperature*x"
>>> x = 5
>>> def lazy_temperature():
    return 78
... 
>>> names = [node.id for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code))
             if type(node) is ast.Name]
>>> ns = {name: (globals()['lazy_%s' % name])()
                 if ('lazy_%s' % name) in globals()
                 else globals()[name] 
          for name in names}
>>> ns
{'x': 5, 'temperature': 78}
>>> eval(code, ns)
390
```

This snippet will load the value out of the current scope, unless there's a function called `lazy_<name>`. This function will be called in case the `<name>` part appears in the expression.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to elaborate? Just curious.

Comment: I have posted a modified question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995920/how-do-i-lazy-evaluate-variables-in-a-python-eval-expression and hope that will attract more constructive feedback. Please post your answer there as well. I think I may use both parts of your answer in my implementation

Comment: it seems the lazy eval code doesn't work. eval result of the code does not change if you change the lazy return value

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a lambda function, and simply execute it whenever you need to, as such:

```
a = lambda : 5*temperature
a()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
> NameError: global name 'temperature' is not defined
temperature = 100
a()
> 500
```

In this way, you don't look for execute unless you consciously want to.

---

However, you could also make sure to only enter the lambda function if temperature exists. You can do that by assigning temperature to `None` in the beginning of your file, and only enter the lambda if you need to:

```
temperature = None
if temperature:
  a()
# do something else
```

---

If you don't want to use the parens `fn() - You could also build a class to do this with a property.

```
class a(object):
  @property
  def temp_calc(self):
    return self.temp*5
```

In this way, you can do the following:

```
temp_obj = a()
temp_obj.temp_calc
```

This will return an error since you don't have a "temp" attribute. But you can assign it if you need to:

```
temp_obj.temp = 5
temp_obj.temp_calc
> 25
```

---

There are lots of options here, i hope these few help.